# Hotkey for curly braces around variable in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, hotkeys, curly-braces

I have the following line of code, and have the **bold** text selected using a cursor:

```
console.log(isAdult)
```

Is there a Visual Studio Code hotkey (on mac) for inserting curly braces either side of my selected text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest way and what I usually do is to press this set of keys:

```
⌘ + D + {
```

By the way here are all the shortcuts for macOS:

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

And here the Windows ones

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a million. I'm not sure why that was so hard to find, but the ⌘ + d + { worked the charm :)

Comment: I am glad it helped you!

Answer (score 3):

Almost every IDE supports wrapping the selected text with braces, quotes and so on.

You need to do next steps:

1. select needed variable/text
2. insert/type an open curly brace symbol
3. IDE will add a close curly brace at the end of selection

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac I use the following while having the text selected:

```
⇧ + { // for braces {text}
```

```
⇧ + ( // for parentheses (text)
```